# Does using stored procedures prevent SQL Injection/XSXX Attacks?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-injection

I'm developing an SaaS app on ASP.NET MVC C# and I was curious if using stored procedures/functions prevents SQL injection and xsxx attacks? I want to do some sort of sanitizing of the data that the user inputs, but I don't know what they best way to do so is.

If I need to do some data scrubbing, what is the best way to approach that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**.

You should use parameterized queries by using a `SqlCommand` and adding the appropriate parameters to the appropriate connection. This will prevent SQL injection. You aren't guaranteed that all avenues will be protected such as if you are using `sp_executesql` from a user string.

SQL injection and XSS attacks are separate issues.

Comment: So I don't need to do any front side scrubbing? As long as I use parameters and proper sprocs, I'm protected from sql injection?

Comment: yes but it doesn't solve XSS which is totally a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

**it Depends**

1. **SQL injection** : Avoid Dynamic SQL in your Stored Procedure as its vulnerable and can be abused using SQL Injection attack, and if unavoidable use `sp_executesql` (As mentioned in Daniel's answer)
   [Better Way](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/06/sql-server-one-trick-of-handling-dynamic-sql-to-avoid-sql-injection-attack/)
2. **XSS**  :For older versions of MVC(aspx view engine) always use `<%: ... %>` which is same as Html.Encode().For @Razor View,`@model.something` is always auto encoded by default unless you are specifically using  `HTML.Raw` . [Nice Read](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2012/03/save-aspnet-mvc-application-against.html)